# Proving $\cosh^2(\cosh x) - \sinh^2 (\sinh x) \geq2$ for real $x$

Tags: inequality, hyperbolic-functions

> Prove that $$\cosh^2(\cosh x) - \sinh^2 (\sinh x) \geq2, \qquad\forall x \in\Bbb{R}$$

It is hard to derive inequality from hyperbolic functions. I have tried hyperbolic expansions, addition theorem, and the definition of the functions.

Please help thank you!

Comment: The minimum is at $x=0$ and is $\cosh^2(1) \approx 2.381$

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $\sinh(\cosh(x)) \geq \cosh(\sinh(x))$, and that is proven e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1299822/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Using the trigonometric identities

$$ \cosh^2 A - \sinh^2 A = 1 \qquad \text{and}\qquad \cosh^2 A - \cosh^2 B = \sinh A \sinh B, $$

we find that

\begin{align*}
&\cosh^2(\cosh x) - \sinh^2(\sinh x) \\
&= \cosh^2(\cosh x) - \cosh^2(\sinh x) + 1 \\
&= \sinh(e^x)\sinh(e^{-x}) + 1.
\end{align*}

So the desired inequality is equivalent to

$$ \sinh(e^x)\sinh(e^{-x}) \geq 1, \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{1} $$

**2.** Now we will show that $\text{(1)}$ is indeed true. Writing $f(x) = \log (\sinh(e^x)\sinh(e^{-x}))$ and computing its derivative, we get

$$ f'(x) = e^x \coth(e^x) - e^{-x}\coth(e^{-x}). $$

Then by noting that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \, t \coth t = \frac{\cosh t \sinh t - t}{\sinh^2 t} > 0, \qquad \forall t > 0, $$

it follows that $t \mapsto t \coth t$ is strictly increasing on $t > 0$. From this, we find that $f'(x)$ is also strictly increasing in $x$ and $f'(0) = 0$ holds. Altogether, we know that $x = 0$ is the global minimum point for $f(x)$, hence proving

$$ \sinh(e^x)\sinh(e^{-x}) = e^{f(x)} \geq e^{f(0)} = \sinh^2(1) > 1 $$

as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you look for the minimum value of function
$$f(x)=\cosh^2(\cosh (x)) - \sinh^2 (\sinh (x)) $$ COmpute the first derivative and simplify it
$$f'(x)=\sinh (x) \sinh (2 \cosh (x))-\sinh (2 \sinh (x)) \cosh (x)$$ The trivial solution $x=0$ is clear because of the first and third hyperbolic sines.

So $f(0)=\cosh^2(\cosh (0))\sim 2.38 > 2$

Now,
$$f''(x)=\cosh (x) (\sinh (2 \cosh (x))-2 \cosh (x) \cosh (2 \sinh (x)))+$$ $$\sinh (x) (2 \sinh
   (x) \cosh (2 \cosh (x))-\sinh (2 \sinh (x)))$$
$$f''(0)=\sinh (2)-2 \sim 1.63 > 0$$ So, $x=0$ is $\color{red}{\large a}$ minimum. However, as @Martin R commented, I did not prove that this is the global minimum.

Comment: This proves that $x=0$ is a local minimum, but where do you show that it is the global minimum? Am I overlooking something? – Also $f(0) = \cosh^2(\cosh(0)) \approx 2.38$.

Comment: @MartinR. I do not ! In fact, I wrote *"So, $x=0$ is $\color{red}{a}$ minimum"$. I shall edit to put the red and quote you. Thanks for pointing the mistake. Cheers :-)

Comment: So  this  does actually not answer the question.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you can use the fact that a local becomes global or a convex function no ?